# Collectionview scroll cross top uiview

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Hello I was using collection-view since year everything was fine , but after update xcode 11 i am facing problem , when i scroll collection-view it cross the boundary of collection-view and cell shows after crossing the top just like in the image please guide me

Code

```
extension BusinessHomeViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
            //AppStrings.DashBoardMenu.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "home", for: indexPath) as! BusinessCollectionViewCell
//        let model = AppStrings.DashBoardMenu[indexPath.row]
      //  cell.lblTitle.text = model



        return cell
    }
```

[image: imagee]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you check to make sure that your collection view's `clipsToBounds` property is set to `true`? You can find this in the interface builder, or set it programmatically via `yourCollectionView.clipsToBounds = true`.

What `clipsToBounds` does is determines whether a view's subviews will still be visible, even if they are moved beyond the parent view's bounds. Setting it to `false` will let the subviews still be visible, even when scrolled beyond the collection view's bounds, so you'll want this property to be set to true.

Comment: Can you share some code as to how you're implementing your collection view in your original question? Are you using a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`?

Comment: nothing i have shared code its just simple code , collection-view on center top and bottom have some views

Comment: Can you set the collectionView's background to something like the color blue? This way we can make sure that the cells are actually going beyond the frame of the collection view. So long as the collection view's `clipsToBounds` is set to true, they shouldn't be visible.

Comment: ok i have added background color to collectionview but color is not moving only cell is moving see in image